# Regular Expression to detect and escape multiple single quotes, other than reserved by JSON

Tags: regex, json

I want to have some Regular Expression which may detect and escape multiple single quotes with double black slash (`\\`). For example if there is `'` then it should become `\\'`

Challenge here is that:

1) It should NOT escape those single quotes which are used by JSON.

Example Below:

```
{'Key1':'Value1','Key2':'Value2'}
```

It should not escape single quotes which are covering keys and values. In above example, none of the quotes should be escaped. 
Any single quotes inside values should be escaped.

2) It should escape MULTIPLE single quotes which are present there inside Value (in some Key value Pair).

Here is the Challenge String which can be used as an example:

Challenge String:

```
{'AddressUsageId':''asd'','Edit':'Edit','SiteUsage':'Bi'llTo','PaymentTerm':'asd','SalesPerson':'S'A@,#$'%^''&*'()<>?`~','Language':'','PrimaryUsage':''''','InternalLocation':'T'est'}
```

It should be escaped like below:

```
{'AddressUsageId':'\'asd\'','Edit':'Edit','SiteUsage':'Bi\'llTo','PaymentTerm':'asd','SalesPerson':'S\'A@,#$\'%^\'\'&*\'()<>?`~','Language':'','PrimaryUsage':'\'\'\'','InternalLocation':'T\'est'}
```

Comment: Why aren't you just using a JSON library to properly encode it, instead of fixing it up with a regexp?

Comment: Looks like XY problem, frankly. Why don't you describe the actual problem you're trying to solve, and not the solution you're thinking about (and which obviously doesn't work as planned)?

Comment: BTW, JSON doesn't use single quotes, it uses double quotes.

Comment: Escaping doubled single quotes could be wrong -- what if the value is the empty string?

Comment: Then it would be followed by comma (or curve bracket), so it's distinguishable. Anyway, as we both said, the whole approach is very wrong. Also, the OP should have stated which language/platform is used.

Comment: Barmar: I tried coupld of parsing functions but those did not help. See if you can list here which you think can add value to this situation.

Comment: Also, JSON String that I am encountering is having single quotes not double. I need a solution to be used in JavaScript.

Comment: Here is the Solution from my side by using Java Script function. I need the regex for the same:     <script>
 
 function removeSingleQuotesFromJSON(str){
  var array = str.split('');
  var strLength =  str.length;
  var resultStr= "";
  for(var i=0; i<strLength; i++){
   if(i>0){
    if(array[i] == "'" && array[i-1] != "{" && array[i+1] != "}" && array[i+1] != ":" && array[i-1] != ":" && !(array[i+1] == "," && array[i+2] == "'") &&       !(array[i-1] == "," && array[i-2] == "'"))
    {
      resultStr+="\\"
    }
   }
   resultStr+=""+array[i];
  }
  return resultStr;
 }
</script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            <script> 
            function removeSingleQuotesFromJSON(str)
            { 
            var array = str.split(''); 
            var strLength = str.length; 
            var resultStr= ""; 
            for(var i=0; i<strLength; i++)
            { 
            if(i>0)
            {
             if(array[i] == "'" && array[i-1] != "{" && array[i+1] != "}" && array[i+1] != ":" && array[i-1] != ":" && !(array[i+1] == "," && array[i+2] == "'") && !(array[i-1] == "," && array[i-2] == "'")) 
                     { 
                        resultStr+="\\" ;
                     } 
             } 
             resultStr+=""+array[i]; 
             } 
              return resultStr;
             } </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes are **NOT** valid JSON. If you pull your string through [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/), it will show you that. The proper way of making a JSON string in PHP is by using [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) on an Array or Object. This will automatically escape quotes if they need to be escaped.

As far as your problem goes. Use the following pseudocode:

```
$s = $json_string without first 2 and last 2 characters
#$a is array of "key':'value"
$a = explode( $s, "','" );

foreach( $a as $i => $keyvalue ) {
  $temp = explode( $keyvalue, "':'" );

  #Now replace all instances of ' with \'
  $temp = str_replace( "'", "\'", $temp );

  #Now do something fancy to stitch everything back together.
}
```